# split method name with regex and ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I would like to use a regex to get every variant of a method name like this:

```
method_name = "my_special_title"
method_name_variants = ["my_special_title", "special_title", "title"]
```

I can do this with:

```
r = /((?:[^_]*_)?((?:[^_]*_)?(.*)))/
r.match("my_special_title").to_a.uniq
=> ["my_special_title", "special_title", "title"]
```

is it possible to have a arbitrary method length so we can have:

```
"my_very_special_specific_method" => ["my_very_special_specific_method", "very_special_specific_method", "special_specific_method", "specific_method", "method"]
```

Comment: Is a regexp the only acceptable answer, or can it be done some other way?

Comment: other way are ok, better when oneliner :) but if one comes with a solution with recursive regex (with named groups) it would be great!

Comment: I really have to take a look at how I18n is implemented in rails (how the keys are interpreted)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
s = "my_very_special_specific_method"
a = s.split('_')
a.length.times.map { |n| a.from(n).join('_') }

=> ["my_very_special_specific_method", "very_special_specific_method", 
    "special_specific_method", "specific_method", "method"]
```

Comment: Oop..sorry. I use [Ruby Facets](http://rubyworks.github.com/facets/) in my `irb`. Sometimes I don't notice the methods come from facets instead of the std lib. `Array#from` returns the last `n` elements. http://rubyworks.github.com/rubyfaux/?doc=http://rubyworks.github.com/facets/docs/facets-2.9.3/core.json#api-class-Array

Comment: Ruby has `last(n)`, no need for `from(n)`.

Comment: Cool! Learnt new methods last and from :) I was only thinking with regex solution though

Answer (score 2):

I would do this that way:

```
method_name = "my_special_title"
parts = method_name.split('_')
arr = []
(0..parts.length-1).each { |i| arr << parts[i..-1].join('_') }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
method_name_variants = [method_name]
while last = method_name_variants.last.split("_", 2)[1]
    method_name_variants.push(last)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def my_method (str,split_by,join_by)
    results = Array.new    
    arr = str.send(:split,split_by)
    arr.count.times do |element|
    results << arr.send(:join,join_by) unless arr.blank?
   arr.pop
 end
results
end
```

Call By

```
my_method("my_special_title",'_','_')
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `"very_special_name".split /_/` => `["very","special","name"]` and then reassemble:

```
method_name = "my_very_special_method_name"
(*pref, base) = method_name.split /_/
a = [base]
pref.reverse.each do |prefix|
    a << (prefix + "_" + a[-1])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In one line:

```
str = "my_very_special_specific_method"
str.split('_').reverse.reduce([]){|acc, s| acc << s+'_'+acc.last.to_s}.reverse.map!{|s| s[0..-2]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = "some_method_name".split '_'
a.map {|element| a[(a.index element)...a.length].join '_' }

# => ["some_method_name", "method_name", "name"]
```